# How to get number of duplicates using a transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, yii

My Code :

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
    try {

        $command->execute();
        $transaction->commit();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $transaction->rollback();
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
```

I am using indexes in the mysql table, So how I can catch the number of rows that actually inserted and the number of rows that where duplicates.

Comment: That's horrible idea to do such things. If you want to check how much of bunch of data is already in table use sample query with `COUNT()` and `id IN()` for example. If you don't want to check if row exists, use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. On big data your method will cause massive load and timing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `command` is a multi-row `INSERT IGNORE`, then `rows_affected` will say how many rows were successfully inserted.  Your code should already know how many rows you were attempting to insert.  The diff is probably the number of rows with a "duplicate key".

Caution.  If you are using `AUTO_INCREMENT`, it will probably increment by the number of rows *attempted*, thereby "burning" some ids.